# Nuxt/firebase Middleware redirect not working

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js, middleware, server-side-rendering

Hi I'm using Nuxt SSR as frontend and firebase as backend and the persistence was set to local.

I have a middleware that needs to check if the user is already login. if the user tries to access the sign in route while already logged, the user will be redirected to business info page. also if the user tries to access other pages first before logging the user will be redirected to the sign in page.

**Problem:**
If I try to access sign in page while already logged, I still access to sign in page and not redirected to business info page

this is my middleware code

```
export default function ({ store, route, redirect }) {
  if (route.path === '/') {
    if (store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
      return redirect('/businessInfo')
    }
  } else if (route.path !== '/') {
    if (!store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
      return redirect('/')
    }
  }
}
```

I already setup other things like NuxtserverInit. I think the problem is that my middleware execute before I could get my credentials, but because I am new I think I'm missing something here please help thank you

Comment: `redirect` works only on the initial render. Try to use `router.push` instead. Also, make a conditional on `store.getters.isLoggedIn` rather than on the path, you just need to know if the user is loggedIn or not. You could of course also make a local middleware (on the page itself) to redirect the user if he tried to reach `/sign-in` while already logged in.

Comment: @kissu I tried router.push but I a type error appear saying 'Cannot read property 'push' of undefined'

Comment: `this.$router.push` right?

Comment: yes, this is my new middleware but the push error still exist

`export default function ({ store, route }) {
  if (!store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
    return this.$router.push('/signin')
  } else if (route.path === '/signin') {
    return this.$router.push('/businessInfo')
  }
}`

Comment: Do you have a [repro] or a github repo? Oh, I'm maybe wrong. `redirect` looks fine looking at this: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/middleware/ What is the issue if you try it like there?

Comment: I actually ask this question a couple of days earlier but got no response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72160236/middleware-getting-called-before-getting-authentication-nuxt-firebase this is more detail question this is the model I follow on creating middleware: https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/tutorials/ssr